# Hamming window with overlap python

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing, librosa, hamming-window

I'm trying to implement the paper [Integrated optimization of underwater acoustic ship-radiated noise
recognition based on two-dimensional feature fusion](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/343510936.pdf).

My biggest problem is transforming `.wav` files to 2d arrays.
In the paper, it's mentioned

> Each originally recorded signal in the database is framed using the hamming window of length 2048 with 50% overlap. With sampling frequency fs=52734 Hz, each sample lasts approximately 40 ms

and also

> 7 levels of WP decomposition with fourth-order
> Symlet wavelet is utilized to decompose each raw sample into
> 128 subbands.

I really appreciate any help in understanding and implementing this using Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compute overlapping windows using [librosa.utils.frame](http://librosa.org/doc/0.6.3/generated/librosa.util.frame.html?highlight=frame#librosa.util.frame), with window_length=2048 and hop_length=1024 (50% overlap).
The window function can be computed using [librosa.filters.get_window](http://librosa.org/doc/0.6.3/generated/librosa.filters.get_window.html?highlight=window#librosa.filters.get_window) with window="hamming"

Each window from the frame function you multiply by the window function.
Then you can use [pywt.wavedec](https://pywavelets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/dwt-discrete-wavelet-transform.html#multilevel-decomposition-using-wavedec) with wavelet="sym" and level=7 to get the output for each frame. It should have 128 dimensions.